# openCv, match features across three images?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I have a stereo camera setup. I am finding features in the images using openCv. What I need to do is match features in a Previous and Current (left) frame, then find the features that match *those* features in the Current (right) frame, so i can triangulate them. I need to end up with three sets of feature descriptors and keyframes, matched across the three images.

My code so far is:

```
    //storage
        cv::Mat descCurrent;
        cv::Mat descCurrentR;
        cv::Mat descPrevious;
        std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keyPntsCurrent;
        std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keyPntsCurrentMatch;
        std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keyPntsCurrentR;
        std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keyPntsPrevious;

    //On the FIRST frame

        keyPntsPrevious = kaze->DetectKeypoints(imLeft, descPrevious);


    // on the CURRENT frame

    //detect the keypoints on Left and Right Current images
        kaze->DetectKeypointsL(imLeft, descCurrent, keyPntsCurrent);
        kaze->DetectKeypointsR(imRight, descCurrentR, keyPntsCurrentR);

    //match to previous frame
        std::vector<cv::DMatch> match = pntMatch->matchPoints(descPrevious, descCurrent);

    //get current - previous descriptors to use for left - right matching
        if (match.size() > 1)
        {
            for (int m = 0; m < match.size(); m++)
        {
           // feature index OF PREVIOUS FRAME DESC
            float* descVector = descCurrent.ptr<float>(match[m].trainIdx);
            descTmp.push_back(descVector);
            //feature index OF CURRENT FRAME KEY            
            keyPntsCurrentMatch.push_back(keyPntsCurrent[match[m].trainIdx]); 

        }

        }
            //  memcpy(descCurrentMatched.data, descTmp.data(), descTmp.size()*sizeof(float));
                descTmp.clear();

                //match to RIGHT frame
                std::vector<cv::DMatch> matchR = pntMatch->matchPoints(descCurrentMatched, descCurrentR);


//triangulate
PointsTo3d(keyPntsCurrentMatch, keyPntsCurrentR, matchR);

    //at end of loop
        descPrevious = descCurrentMatched;
        keyPntsPrevious = keyPntsCurrent;
        keyPntsCurrentMatch.clear();
```

This line:
`memcpy(descCurrentMatched.data, descTmp.data(), descTmp.size()*sizeof(float));`

currently crashes the application, giving no error. So my question is:

Is this a valid approach to match features across three images in a dynamic video stream?

If so, why might that `memcpy` be crashing?

thank you.

Comment: Is descCurrentMatched.data a pointer or a member function? Do you need yo call .data() to get the pointer? Surely attempting to overwrite the data function would crash on many systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! Minutes after posting, i figured out a workaround. It is possible to detect all the keypoints, and then pass the matched previous-current keypoints into this function:

```
cv::Mat features;
cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor> extractor = cv::AKAZE::create();
extractor->compute(imLeft, keyPntsCurrentMatch, features);
```

This will output new descriptors from the keypoints that you pass in.